# How to use Kafka with Neo4j community edition

Tags: plugins, neo4j, apache-kafka, stream

I installed Neo4j and I can access the server. I can make nodes though cypher. 
Now I want to use it for data streams. But I'm not sure how to do so. I just started Neo4j and I'm struggling with installing 'Stream Plugin'. 
Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should copy the [jar files](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-streams/releases/) for the Neo4j streams plugin directly into your `/plugins` folder and configure the connections to Kafka and Zookeeper as well as other Neo4j property values at the neo4j.conf file as described [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/neo4j-streams/current/quickstart/#_neo4j_streams_plugin_2). For example:

```
kafka.zookeeper.connect=zookeeper-host:2181
kafka.bootstrap.servers=kafka-host:9092
```

Alternatively, if you are looking only for a sink connection from Kafka (i.e. moving records from Kafka topics to into Neo4j), you can also use Kafka Connect with the the supported *Kafka Connect Neo4j Sink*. More at https://www.confluent.io/hub/neo4j/kafka-connect-neo4j

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. I downloaded Neo4j desktop in Ubuntu 16.0. Then I found the plugins folder (something like: /home/brahmanacsw/.config/Neo4j Desktop/Application/neo4jDatabases/database-eef1b9be-5bc1-4237-a5db-23feb465e989/installation-4.0.3/plugins) Then I copied the .jar (neo4j-streams-4.0.1.jar) file there. Do I have to install .jar file? I can not find a file named "neo4j.conf" inside neo4j-streams-4.0.1.jar. Please help me.

Comment: You're welcome. The neo4j.conf file is probably located at the directories "/etc/neo4j/" or your "/home/brahmanacsw/.config/Neo4j Desktop/Application/neo4jDatabases/database-eef1b9be-5bc1-4237-a5db-23feb465e989/installation-4.0.3/".

Comment: I changed the .config file. But I'm getting these errors.                                                
2020-05-19 04:10:52.004+0000 INFO  [neo4j] Initializing Kafka Connector
2020-05-19 04:12:52.658+0000 ERROR [neo4j] Error initializing the streaming producer: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment                                                                                                2020-05-19 04:12:52.733+0000 INFO  [neo4j] Starting the Kafka Sink
2020-05-19 04:14:53.035+0000 ERROR [neo4j] Error initializing the streaming sink: